# Why is the minimize window function disabled sometimes?

Tags: window-manager

Once in a while, the yellow minimize button on some windows is greyed out, and the Window → Minimize menu entry is likewise disabled. Right now, for example, this is the case with two open Terminal windows. If I open a new Terminal window, it can be minimized, but the old ones remain unminimizable (if that's a word). I tend to think of this as a bug. Or is it a feature? If so, what causes it, and what can I do to enable minimization of these windows?

Comment: That looks like a bug, are you on the latest OS X with all updates installed? I can't reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Are any other menu items disabled? The menu items for quitting applications (and sometimes other menu items like the ones for closing documents) become disabled all the time on my account for some reason.

Comment: Strange.  I use Terminal.app on Lion all the time, and I don't recall ever seeing this.

Comment: @houbysoft: Yes, latest Lion, all updates. But I have seen it on older versions too; not sure for how long. Also this is on a new laptop. Rather than using Migration Assistant, I set this one up from scratch, to avoid bringing in cruft from countless generations of laptops. Also, I can't reliably reproduce the problem. It seems to pop up at random.

Comment: @LauriRanta: No, the only other disabled menu items are expected ones.

Comment: Hmm … the problem disappeared spontaneously (for now). I still haven't the foggiest notion if it is because of something I did, or if it's just random.

Comment: I hadn't seen this problem in a long time, but now it is happening again, on OS X 10.8.5 this time. My iTerm windows cannot be minimized. (It's been so long, I had forgotten I asked this question myself! I came across it by googling. 8-)

Comment: – And just a sleep later, minimize is back to normal. Weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was [an old QuickTime bug that caused the minimise button to become disabled on some windows](http://www.microshell.com/sysadmin/macosx/mac-yellow-minimize-button-grayed-out/).

But also be aware [the app can disable the minimise button itself](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/SettingWindowAppearance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000232-BBCDDHGE).

Comment: Thanks! Thought I haven't seen this problem in what seems like ages, now I know at least a little bit more about it. I'll accept this answer, even though I may not be able to verify it.

Comment: Holy moly the steps for that Quicktime bug worked, thanks!